# Get PublishProfile for an Azure WebApp using Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

How can we get the PublishProfile for an Azure WebApp using Powershell? 
I'm not looking for `Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile` cmdlet. That gives me the PublishSettings for the whole subscription. 
I want the PublishSettings only for that particular Azure WebApp.

We can get this file when we click the following link on Azure Portal.
[image]

The content of the file is something like shown below.
[image]

Can someone please help me get this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually, we have a new PowerShell command:

```
Get-AzureRMWebAppPublishingProfile -ResourceGroupName myRG -Name webAppName
```

That will give you the PublishProfile in a single command!

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
After seeing your answer I secretly hoped that it would not be this simple.;)
Omg, I struggled so much to get this info.

Comment: After hours of struggling, trying to do this with the REST API (and failed), this worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can get the publishing credentials for your site using the ResourceManager cmdlets as follows:

```
# List publishingcredentials
$resource = Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName <Resource Group Name> -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName <Site Name>/publishingcredentials -Action list -ApiVersion 2015-08-01 -Force
$resource.Properties
```

This returns a JSON blob with the same information as the publish profile:

```
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/sitename/publishingcredentials/$sitename",
  "name": "sitename",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/publishingcredentials",
  "location": "West US",
  "tags": {
    "hidden-related:/subscriptions/subid/resourcegroups/adriang-test/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/serverfarmname": "empty"
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": null,
    "publishingUserName": "$sitename",
    "publishingPassword": "password",
    "metadata": null,
    "isDeleted": false,
    "scmUri": "https://$sitename:password@sitename.scm.azurewebsites.net"
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry Adrian. Though your answer helped me solve the issue, I made Ahmed's answer as the correct answer as it is a direct cmdlet and would help others who face this issue.

Comment: This answer is more useful to me as it allows me to extract the password and then pass it to a build/deploy script.

Comment: To use this with a Azure Website deployment slot, change the Resource Type and then specify your slot in the resource name. 

-ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/config
- -ResourceName <Site Name>/<Slot Name>publishingcredentials

Answer (score 2):

Also, to fetch the publishing profile specific to a deployment slot , we could use

```
Get-AzureRMWebAppSlotPublishingProfile -ResourceGroupName Default-Web-EastUS -Name propertiesdemo -OutputFile none -Slot dev
```